# Advantage Database Replication

Tags: replication, sybase, advantage-database-server

I have a client that wants two sites to have the ability to sync databases so information at Site A can be synced with Site B so the two sites can look at the same data.

I'm not even sure of the infrastructure required. Would a VPN required to connect the 2 databases or would an internet based database work ie/Site A to InternetDatabase and Site B to InternetDatabase. Each site copies data to it periodically and then the InternetDatabase syncs it and the Sites can then pull data down.

My other thought was something like Dropbox.  If Site A and Site B use a Dropbox account to sync the ADT files etc can the database at each site then sync with those ADT files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two sites update completely different tables, then something like Dropbox might work for that. Dropbox does not synchronize/merge the contents of files. That means if both site A and site B updated some file, then you would be responsible for writing the code to merge the changes.

Advantage Database Server has support for [replication built in](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10/master_replication_overview.htm?zoom_highlightsub=replication) natively, so that would likely be the simplest solution. Advantage replication is performed on a record-by-record basis and is handled asynchronously. If the target database cannot be reached, the updates are stored in a queue and processed periodically.  If the connection between the two sites is open/available constantly, the lag between the source update and the replicated update is typically small but obviously depends on the network bandwidth and latency.

You could use a VPN for the connection between the two sites, but it would not be required. If you do not use some kind of VPN, though, you should make sure the communication is encrypted between the two sites (it is an option when setting up the subscriptions).

**Edit** For the communication, all you need is "normal" network connectivity. The primary issue is dealing with things like firewalls and NAT. With Advantage, you define which port it uses.  If you use a TCP/IP connection, you would need to make sure the configured port allows inbound connections to the ads.exe process.  You can use UDP as well, but if you are dealing with firewalls, it is probably going to be simpler with TCP.

Your question about duplicate keys is a good one.  If both sites either add a record with the same primary key or update the same record concurrently, then it results in a conflict. There is an option to simply ignore conflicts in which case the last update wins.  More realistically, you would want to write an [ON CONFLICT trigger](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10/master_triggers_and_replication.htm?zoom_highlightsub=conflict%2Btrigger) to handle the conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Does sound like replication is the key.  The 2 databases are the same schema just two sites entering data.  If I didn't use a VPN how would the 2 sites and databases communicate? Also how does the replication handle duplicate primary keys. To recap Site A needs a copy of Site B data and vice versa

Comment: @Jon, Good questions.  I added some edits that hopefully clarify it some.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Just to also expand the site issue. It would be all via the internet as Site A might be in London and Site B in Edinburgh so is this still viable? The sites wouldnt be updating the same record concurrently because each site has a seperate database, so it might be that a PersonID of 10 is created at both sites but when we want to sync how will it be handled? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jon, That should work fine.  When you set up the connection path, you probably want to use the form \\ipaddr:port\path\dictionary.add. As long as the firewalls allow traffic to that address, you should be fine.

Comment: @Jon, I was unclear on "same record".  I did mean the same logical record (ID=10 at both sites is the same logical record).  To handle the situation you describe, it might make sense to include a SiteID column and then create the primary key on SiteID;PersonID.  That would avoid conflict issues with the primary keys.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Makes sense. Big task of now adding SiteID to every table :-)

Comment: @Jon, It is worth noting that is not the only solution.  Another possibility (depending on how keys are generated would be to simply add some "site ID" value (e.g., A or B) to an existing identifier field (assuming it is not a numeric field).  The goal simply is to make a unique ID across two sites.  GUIDs would work too, but they  have more expense in terms of space not to mention it would be a hassle to change existing schemas, foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Note: ADS 'pushes' data only. Data 'pull' is not an option.